# Ngx-guage percent values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So I've been trying to display percent values but ngx-gauge only displays float values.

Documentation on ngx-gauge

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-gauge

What I want

[image]

What I get

[image]

Trying to have "%" at the end of my value.

HTML

```
 <ngx-gauge style="color:rgba(0,0,0,100); font-size:100px;"type="semi" cap="semi" thick="12" size="100" [foregroundColor]="color"
        backgroundColor="rgba(176, 242, 206, 0.54)"


        value="{{value}}"
       [label]="label"
        max="1"
       [append]="sleep.gaugeAppendText">

 </ngx-gauge>
```

.TS

```
 value = 0.64
 label = "Pepper"
```

Comment: Never used it before but if you have a max set at 1, how could you expect any value greater than 1?

Comment: All values passed through will be less than 1 in these scenarios. The gauge compares the max value with the value passed to draw the diagram. Like 0.64 is only 64% complete in the above picture.

Comment: What is `sleep.gaugeAppendText` in this case?

Comment: I actually had sleep.gaugeAppendText set to `" "`. Not really too familiar with ngx-gauge myself. Turned out that was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gauge-ovkljq)

```
  <ngx-gauge style="color:white; font-size:100px;" 
        type="arch" 
        thick="5"
        size="200"  
        foregroundColor='gold'                
        [value]="value"
        [label]="label"
        [max]="max"
        [min]="min"
        [append]="gaugeAppendText">
 </ngx-gauge>
```

in ts

```
gaugeAppendText="%"
```